# How can I set different ringtones - one for new email and one for new SMS in Nexus One?

Tags: sms, email, ringtone

Currently I can't find the `selection box` anywhere in the configuration in my Nexus One to allow this; i.e. they are the same and when I'm expecting SMS from my friend, I get distracted by the emails and vice versa...

So, is it possible everyone? And if it is please show me how. Thank you!

Comment: To deviate from the generic notification ringtone, the app itself needs to support it. Are you using the stock email and SMS apps? Gmail, at least, allows for changing the notification ringtone that it uses. (In fact, you can setup individual notifications by account by label.)

Comment: @Everett You are correct! Thank you. Please move your comment as an answer so it would be selected as `accepted`

Comment: Sure thing. Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To deviate from the generic notification ringtone, the app itself needs to support it. Are you using the stock email and SMS apps? Gmail, at least, allows for changing the notification ringtone that it uses. (In fact, you can setup individual notifications by account by label.)

Answer (score 3):

If I go to Message - Settings I see options to choose different ringtones. Similarly if I go to  Gmail - Settings - Main account, I can see options to choose ringtones. But I am using HTC Desire.

Comment: Thank you. It would help HTC users though.